# Need help to resolve conflicts with flexslider, waypoint.js and google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider, jquery-waypoints

I am developing a wordpress website, and I am stuck with a conflict between flexslider, google maps and waypoint.js. I am using waypoint to stick the navigation to the top when scrolling. The effect can be seen here `http://arunbhat.com/wordpress` 
When scrolling up and down, the navigation flickers, disappears.

```
custom.js file

$('.navbar-wrapper').waypoint('sticky');

if ($(".worklogo").length>0)
    {
      $('.worklogo').flexslider(
      {
         animation: "slide", //This line causing the issue
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 210,
        itemMargin: 5,

      });
    }

//Works when entire code below is removed

if ( $("#qva-googlemap").length>0 )
    { 
        var _self = $("#qva-googlemap"),
           $longitude = _self.data("longitude"),
           $latitude  = _self.data("latitude"),
           $title  = _self.data("title"),
           $image  = _self.data("image");

           if ( $longitude != '' && $latitude != '' )
           {

            var $latlng             = new  google.maps.LatLng($longitude,$latitude),
                $myOptions          = {
                    zoom            : 16,
                    center          : $latlng,
                    panControl      : false,
                    zoomControl     : false,
                    scrollwheel     : false,
                    scaleControl    : false,
                    mapTypeControl  : false,
                    draggable       : false,
                    // mapTypeId       : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                },

                // $tabContact         = ('tab-contact');

            // $content.bind('easytabs:after', function(evt,tab,panel) {
                // if ( tab.hasClass($tabContact) ) {
            $map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("qva-googlemap"), $myOptions);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: $latlng,
                map: $map, 
                title: $title,
                icon: $image
            });
         }
    }
```

The above codes which I have mentioned is causing the issue when removed, the navigation works fine. But I need all the plugins to work. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe try adding GMap as an `iframe`?

Comment: Even the flexslider is causing the issue.